# How can I set my code not to check regular expressions at view loading time in C# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezhGq.png)

When I run my project I see that regular expressions like `[Required]` is checked before entering any data and submitting.
Is anyone here able to help?

```
public ActionResult Add(Student stdnt)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
    {
        BlStudent Bl = new BlStudent();
        if (Bl.Add(stdnt) == true)
        {
            ViewBag.message = "Successfully Added!";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.message = "Unsuccessful to Add";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.message = "Please enter the information correctly!";
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: _Probably_ by having a separate Get() and Post() method, but it's really unclear from the limited information in your question. How do you see that the validation attributes are checked?

Comment: I posted the image of loading time before entering any data. I will try Get and Post methods, Tnx a lot

Comment: It looks like your problem is solved in your second code snippet - when the page first loads, you have no validation errors, and after submit, it *does* validate the model.
Is there something else that you want to happen? Or does that solve it?

Comment: @CarenRose yeah it solved! my problem was just about that part.

Comment: @Farimah you should add it as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem by using `[HTTPPOST]` and `[HTTPGET]`! Now the regular expressions are not checked on loading. Just as you send the data to the server by clicking the button, it happens.

this is on load: [image: On load form]

and this is after sending to the server: [image: After clicking the button]

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Student stdnt)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
        {
            BlStudent Bl = new BlStudent();
            if (Bl.Add(stdnt) == true)
            {
                ViewBag.message = "Successfully Added!";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.message = "Unsuccessful to Add";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.message = "Please enter the information correctly!";
        }
        return View();
    }

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Add()
{
    return View();
}
```